# Retrofit detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath error in OKHttp 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using `Retrofit-1.6.0` + `okhttp-2.0.0-RC1` in my project . 
when i run the project i get the error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Retrofit detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath.
To use OkHttp with this version of Retrofit, you'll need:
1. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0 (or newer)
2. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0 (or newer)
Note that OkHttp 2.0.0+ is supported!
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, square has released 2.0 RC2 on github, but not on maven:

https://github.com/square/okhttp

But you still need okhttp-urlconnection (RC1) which is only on maven:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp

And don't forget okhttp 2.0 is now dependent on okio:

https://github.com/square/okio

Comment: will you please tell me whats the advantage of adding okhttp along with retrofit as retrofit can work even without okhttp?

Answer (score 13):

Even with OkHTTP 2 you need to import the urlConnection extra

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'`

Answer (score 2):

I had picasso/Retrofit complaning the same way you do. This configuration worked for me:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Actually if you're using retrofit 1.9.0 you **don't need to import 'okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'**.

_If you are using OkHttp you must use version 2.0 or newer and you no longer need to use the okhttp-urlconnection shim._
[Retrofit 1.9.0 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: @Ryan I can confirm that I'm having an EOFError using retrofit 1.9.0, that does not appear anymore after importing retrofit 1.9.0+okhttp2.3+okhttp-urlconnection2.3. This error happened to me just now, on a Samsung SIII